# get count of repeated values in a list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a following list of dictionary:

```
[{'S_Length': '5.1', 'S_Width': '3.5', 'Predicate': 'I-s', 'P_Width': '0.2', 'P_Length': '1.4'},
 {'S_Length': '3.1', 'S_Width': '7.5', 'Predicate': 'I-k', 'P_Width': '4.2', 'P_Length': '9.1'},
{'S_Length': '5.1', 'S_Width': '2.5', 'Predicate': 'I-s', 'P_Width': '0.2', 'P_Length': '4.4'},
{'S_Length': '5.1', 'S_Width': '7.5', 'Predicate': 'I-M', 'P_Width': '0.2', 'P_Length': '1.4'},
{'S_Length': '5.1', 'S_Width': '1.5', 'Predicate': 'I-s', 'P_Width': '0.2', 'P_Length': '1.4'},]
```

In the above data, i need to find all the `Predicate : I-s` that has `S_Length : 5.1`.
What would be the right and easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehesion:

```
mylist = [{'S_Length': '5.1', ...]
result = [x for x in mylist if x['Predicate'] == 'I-s' and x['S_Length'] == '5.1']
## in this case, len(result) == 3
```

or if you just need the total count and not the actual list:

```
ct = len([x for x in mylist if x['Predicate'] == 'I-s' and x['S_Length'] == '5.1'])
```

Comment: is there anyway to keep the count too? I mean the total values in the list that satisfy `x['Predicate'] == 'I-s' and x['S_Length'] == '5.1'`

Comment: @ClintWhaley isn't it simply the length of the resulting list?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a list of the dictionaries that match your conditions, but just their count, you can use a `sum` call on a generator expression:

```
sum(x['Predicate'] == 'I-s' and x['S_length'] == '5.1' for x in my_list)
```

This works because Python's `bool` type inherits from `int`, and its instances `True` and `False` have the integer values `1` and `0`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
dicts = [{'S_Length': '5.1', 'S_Width': '3.5', ..... }, { ...]
print [
    d
    for d in dicts
    if d.get('Predicate') == 'I-s' and d.get('S_Length') == '5.1'
]
```

Comment: I think you mean `print [d for d in dicts if d.get('Predicate') == 'I-s' and d.get('S_Length') == '5.1']`  In Python, `where` does not exist.